# Kotlin+Mockito2: ClassNotFoundException for presenter tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

I have a sample app written in Kotlin based on [CleanArchitecture-Android](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) style. Below is the configuration for the app:

**presentation/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':domain')

  def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
  def commonDependencies = rootProject.ext.commonDependencies

  testCompile testingDependencies.junit
  testCompile testingDependencies.mockito // org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.10.0
}
```

**presentation/src/test/java/package/RepoPreferencesPresenterTest.kt**

```
internal class RepoPreferencesPresenterTest : UnitTest() {
  // FIXME: Mocking fails
  @Mock private lateinit var mockRepositoriesUseCase: RepositoriesUseCase
  @Mock private lateinit var mockView: RepoPreferencesContract.View

  private lateinit var presenter: RepoPreferencesPresenter<RepoPreferencesContract.View>

  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    presenter = RepoPreferencesPresenter(mockRepositoriesUseCase)
    presenter.onAttach(mockView)
  }
}
```

When I try to run the testcase, I'd face with `ClassNotFoundException` everytime. Unable to mock the UseCase present in **domain module** for the presenter tests, other than that app is running fine.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/sample/domain/usecases/RepositoriesUseCase;
......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.domain.usecases.RepositoriesUseCase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Any idea how to solve the problem? (I'd also tried using mock-maker-inline but it doesn't work)

Comment: You should try using: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin. Here is an example here: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gif-example.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'd tried using `com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin` too, same error. The example repo you had linked have single module with different package names(data, presentation) but mine has multiple modules (domain, data, presentation) like the clean-architetcture-java implementation.

Comment: Try to initialize mock objects. In @Before method use first: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by manually specifying the classpaths for all the modules in the `presentation/build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
    main.java.srcDirs += '../data/src/main/java'
    main.java.srcDirs += '../entities/src/main/java'
    main.java.srcDirs += '../domain/src/main/java'
  }
```

*Settings*: Gradle version "3.0.0-beta6", Android Studio 3.0-Beta 6.